# How do I find the variance for a range of numbers?

Tags: standard-deviation, variance

Basically, my homework is asking me to find the variance based on a frequency table. But the frequency table looks like this:

Frequency Table:
Salary  Number of Employees
5,001–10,000    **8 employees**
10,001–15,000   **12 employees**
15,001–20,000   **20 employees**
20,001–25,000   **17 employees**
25,001–30,000   **13 employees**

**I know how to find the variance, I just don't know how to when the numbers are for example 5000k-1000k --it's not one number, it's a range of numbers.**

Answer (score 1):

Since the range is always 5000 units you could just use the mean of the two boundaries of each category and compute the variance with these values. I assume there is no additional information given? (sorry, can't comment yet, hence my post as an answer)

Comment: very true, i could do that. The professor was not specific